# Best Curl Package/Replacement in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, curl, oauth-2.0, request, fitbit

I was looking through other posts for replacements for Curl in nodejs, especially with complex behaviors as such:

```
 -H 'Authorization: Basic MjJCTUpROjczNzY0YzkwOWQ2MDczZDRjYzA0YWZhZDBlMDVhMThm' \
 --data "clientId=22BMJQ" \
 --data "grant_type=authorization_code" \
 --data "redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fcallback" \
 --data "code=5f10eff73e8daf2049be22bb079beee57036c7a5" \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
https://api.fitbit.com/oauth2/token
```

Are there any packages you would recommend or have ideas on how the above request could be replicated in nodejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you don't only want to call OAuth 2.0 endpoints but also other endpoints with the curl alternative, I made good experiences with [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch). The code with node-fetch is more readable and you can work with response very easily in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [OpenId Client](https://github.com/panva/node-openid-client), which is a certified library. It will make life easier once you're familiar with it.

Here are a couple of links that you might find useful, to understand the basics of the coding model:

- [Authorization Code Flow Tutorial](https://codeburst.io/how-to-implement-openid-authentication-with-openid-client-and-passport-in-node-js-43d020121e87)
- [API Sample Code of Mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authenticator.ts)